# error while inserting null data in mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7, phpmyadmin

Whenever I am inserting any blank data in my table it works on XAMPP but it does not work on my IIS server having PHP version 5.3 and MySQL version 5.5 I found error. What setting should I do in my configuration file so that any null value and blank data can be inserted, not only that if my table has five columns and if in one query page only two data is to be inserted rest is not written then also it shows error which is

```
 insert failed Field 'XXX' doesn't have a default value
 insert failed Data truncated for column 'Man_Days' at row 1
```

Is there any setting changes which can be done in my.ini or php.ini or config.inc.php

Comment: check your sql mode in my.ini where mysql is present. change your strict mode to blank i.e "". It will work. my.ini is found inside your C:\Program Files\mysql\my.ini

Answer (score 0):

Firstly You must try to avoid inserting blank data in table. if it's not possible then try to insert the field which have value. So You may try to use Your mysql insert query like below:-

```
insert into table_name (field1,field3) values(value1,value2);
```